# Ubuntu Server in Virtualbox working slowly for Ruby On Rails

Tags: virtualbox, rails

I have quite big rails app to develop frontend for, most work with design involve Adobe Illustrator and Photoshop, tried run them in VM but they work very buggy.

So decided to go other way - to run virtual box with rails app on windows host.

But it run very slowly - under native Ubuntu 14.04 page generation time is about 1-1.5 seconds, under Ubuntu Server 14.04 in virtualbox page generation time is about 5-10 seconds, which is unacceptably slow.

I've tried to play literally with all parameters of virtualbox settings, give it 4 cpu, 1 cpu, 512 ram, 8gb ram, enable/disable hardware virtualizations, pae/nx etc. (i.e. toggle and tried literally each checkbox and select values)

On ubuntu server side tried to increase cache pressure and tried latest kernel 3.18

Both methods above didn't show any improvements.

What's interesting, if I run CPU intensive task it work almost as good on virtual machine as on native ubuntu, but rendering views somehow painfully slow.

Can someone help how to solve this problem, what could be tried more?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the code located that is running?  Within the VM or in a shared folder?